# Deleting with SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-delete

### VB 2012

table 1

```
Kubun |Name | Code | Date   | Time
1     |AA   | 10001|20210101|8:30
1     |AA   | 10001|20210101|9:00
1     |BB   | 10002|20210101|8:30
1     |BB   | 10002|20210101|9:00
2     |AA   | 10001|20210101|14:00
2     |AA   | 10001|20210101|17:30
2     |BB   | 10002|20210101|14:00
2     |BB   | 10002|20210101|17:30
```

I want to delete all data except minimum time from Kubun 1 and maximum time from Kubun 2.
I would be grateful if you could help this solution.

Comment: What is the type of the `Time` column?

Comment: 'Time' = integer , not Null

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question information, if you are looking something in SQL-Query solution, then try to use something like this:

`Delete From Table1 Where [Time] != (Select Min([Time]) From Table1) and [Time] != (Select Max([Time]) From Table1)`

Update Query to Delete Records based on Max Time and Min Time based on Name

```
Delete t1 From Table1 t1 
Join 
   (Select [Name], max([Time]) maxTime, min([Time]) minTime From Table1 Group by [Name]) t2
    on 
      (t1.[Name] = t2.[Name] and t1.[Time] = t2.maxTime) OR 
      (t1.[Name] = t2.[Name] and t1.[Time] = t2.minTime)
```

Comment: With this way, I did it and could delete all data except min(time) and max. but I want to remain max & min [Time] for each person from  Name column.